# EJB containing POJO instance with transaction

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.0, pojo

I have created POJO facades to be used by Stateless EJBs. These POJO classes contains convenient CRUD methods using Entity beans with transactions. My persistence.xml is defined to use JTA. However my POJO classes is using manual transactions. I think that is the reason why I'm getting this error:

***"A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()"***

How do I make this works? A short code example would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no good and recommended ways to do that. Guess I just have to convert all of them POJOs to session beans